# programmatically minimize a JInternalFrame?

Tags: java, swing, minimize, jinternalframe

Is there any way to programmatically minimize a JInternalFrame?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`setIcon()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html#setIcon%28boolean%29) "Iconifies or de-iconifies this internal frame…"

Comment: and JInternalFrame#addInternalFrameListener() return all posible statuses for that +1

Comment: Ug, I knew it was probably something simple. The method name is misleading to me. setIcon seems to indicate that you would be setting the image icon - or maybe I'm no good at UI speak :) at any rate, thanks!

Comment: Yes, this terminology is confusing; I've edited/added tags, accordingly.