# gaining a focus of JInternalFrame object

Tags: java, swing, focus, jinternalframe

What happens when you minimize JInternalFrame object using built-in icon located in the corner (next to maximizing and closing ones)?
I have a JInternalFrame in JDesktopPane and my problem is following:
When I minimize one frame it is being minimized. When I try to re-open the frame via using JMenu it works for first time. When I do this procedure again, the frame is being minimized but not re-opened, but when I click manually on a iconified frame, it shows properly.
I tried to do combination of setSelected, moveToFront, setIcon, setVisible, activateFrame, or requestFocus, but still no effects.
I wonder what happens when you minimize JInternalFrame, what is being set, what should do to get focus of a particular frame, and why the procedure it works for the first time and not others?
thanks

Comment: could you provide a [sscce](http://sscce.org/) ?

Comment: There are some example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9414728/230513).

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work fine for me

```
try {

    if (myFrame.isIcon()) {

        myFrame.setIcon(false);
        miDoShowHide.setText("Hide");

    } else {

        myFrame.setIcon(true);
        miDoShowHide.setText("Show");

    }

} catch (Exception exp) {

    exp.printStackTrace();

}
```

I set up a menu item that would call this functionality.  I tested by using the menu to min, restore, min, restore.  I minimized the frame by the frame control and restored via the menu, minimized by the menu and restored by the frame control.

Also make sure that the `JInternalFrame` is set to `Iconifiable` (`setIconifiable(true)`) otherwise you will experience some strange results