# Iconifiable for JInternalFrame not working in Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jinternalframe

I am using netbeans to build a UI which as JInternalFrames for a Java Desktop Application. However, when I enable the iconifiable property of the JInternalFrames it doesn't work.The image below dipicts what happens.I have not modified the code generated by netbeans.

[Image](https://i40.tinypic.com/v43y9f.png):

[image]

Comment: Read the JInternalFrame API and follow the link to the Swing tutorial on `How to Use Internal Frames`. You can download the working example and compare the code to see how your code is different. We can't help you because you didn't post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). You also haven't accepted answers from other questions in the past.

Comment: You might also try this complete [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9422246/230513).

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem thanks. I was adding the JInternalFrames to JFrame instead of the JDesktopPane.`CourseAdmin courseAdmin = new CourseAdmin();
        this.jdpMainPane.add(courseAdmin);
        courseAdmin.setVisible(true);`